# Django haystack custom query with group by

Tags: python, mysql, django, elasticsearch

I am dealing with *haystack* and *elasticsearch*. Is there a possibility to pull out results that matches such mysql query:

`SELECT name, count(*) FROM article WHERE (here goes some where clause) GROUP BY name;`

article is some kind of view that aggregates all info that are used for searching. Based on that I've made haystack index. And now after making some searches I want to add additional summary about that searching.

I've found some kind of solution:

```
articles = SearchQuerySet().filter(some_custom_filter_options)

summary = articles.facet('name').facet_counts()['fields']['name']
```

Unfortunately the `facet` `'fields'` are limited in length up to 100? Because upper query gives me more than 100 rows...

Is there any way to achieve that? I know that I could parse it with simple for loop but sometimes I get more than 50k results.

Answer (score 1):

Django haystack support multiple backends but not with all of their features. Elasticsearch Aggregations is not supported on django haystack. See this [feature request](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1006).

This is the reason why I personnaly stopped using Haystack to take the most of elasticSearch using [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/).

Anyway, with Haystack, you have two ways of doing this Aggregation :

**Using the Low level API**

```
from haystack import connections

query = {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}

backend = connections.all()[0].get_backend()
raw_results = backend.conn.search(query, index=backend.index_name, doc_type='modelresult')
results = backend._process_results(raw_results)
```

More info on [ElasticSearch aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/_executing_aggregations.html) and [Haystack ElasticSearch JSON Queries](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/927).

**Using Hastack + Django ORM** with the cost of one more query.

```
from django.db.models import Count

articles_id = SearchQuerySet().filter(some_custom_filter_options).values_list('id', flat=True)

articles = Article.objects.filter(id__in=articles_id).annotate(nb_article=Count('name'))
```

Comment: yes I know but that's the old way and I wonder if it's possible to use only SearchQuerySet instead of QuerySet API

Comment: This fails for me: Article.objects.filter(id__in=articles_id).annotate(nb_article=Count('name')) is returning a list of article objects, each with nb_article = 1 because 'name' is an attribute of article and not a related object with a one-to-many relationship. I understood the question to be: return a list of unique article names with associated number of articles.

Comment: Solution to return a list of unique article names with associated number of articles: articles = Article.objects.filter(id__in=articles_id).values('name').annotate(nb_article=Count('name'))